# THREE JS TextureLoader

Tags: webgl, three.js, textures

I am trying to add texture to a model that I converted to json and imported from 3ds Max. I searched but didn't find any code online which applies texture to json models using three.js r53. I guess the way Three.js handles textures changed from previous version. Any guidance?

Following is my code:

```
var texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var tex=texloader.load("second.jpg");
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: tex });

loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "js/JsonModels/toothz.js", function( geometry, mat ) {
    mat[0].shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mat);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
    mesh.position.y = 0;
    mesh.position.x = 0;
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

Answer (score 10):

May be the other answer worked on the older version, this is how I got it working

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load(url);

// Add the event listener
textureLoader.addEventListener('load', function(event){

    // The actual texture is returned in the event.content
    sphere.material.map = event.content;

});
```

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: This is the better answer, and thanks for the documentation! It's working now. Before my object was being added to the scene with... no actual image!

Comment: What is suggested in the documentation doesn't work for me.

Comment: The link above is not valid, try this one https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:
This post was a year old when I answered it, and it seems like my answer got posted shortly before the API changed.
This answer won't work (trusting the words of [Kumar Sanket Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375245/4730332), haven't tested)

Even if this is older than a year, since I came around it now when searching for the solution:

textureloader gives you a callback once the texture is loaded:

```
var texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
texloader.load("second.jpg", function(tex) {

  var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: tex });

  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load( "js/JsonModels/toothz.js", function( geometry, mat ) {
      mat[0].shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
      material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mat);
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      mesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
      mesh.position.y = 0;
      mesh.position.x = 0;
      scene.add( mesh );
  } );
});
```

This works for the example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on September 2019

> ```
> load(
>     url: string,
>     onLoad?: ( texture: Texture ) => void,
>     onProgress?: ( event: ProgressEvent ) => void,
>     onError?: ( event: ErrorEvent ) => void
> ): Texture;
>
> setCrossOrigin( crossOrigin: string ): TextureLoader;
> ```

**Usage:**

```
// instantiate a loader & load a resource
new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    // resource URL
    'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg',

    // onLoad callback
     ( texture )=> {
        // in this example we create the material when the texture is loaded
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            map: texture
         } );
    },

    // onProgress callback currently not supported
    undefined,

    // onError callback
    ( err )=> {
        console.error( 'An error happened.' );
    }
);
```