# How do I load multiple textures with the new THREE.TextureLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I load multiple textures with the new THREE.TextureLoader from Three.js ?

At the moment I'm loading my textures like this:

```
  var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture1.jpg');
  var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture2.jpg');
  var texture3 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture3.jpg');
  var texture4 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture4.jpg');
  var texture5 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture5.jpg');
  ...
```

And Google chrome's developer tool give the following warning:

> THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture is being deprecated. Use
>   THREE.TextureLoader() instead.

**My attempt with the new THREE.TextureLoader:**

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

loader.load('texture1.jpg',function ( texture1 ) {});
loader.load('texture2.jpg',function ( texture2 ) {});
loader.load('texture3.jpg',function ( texture3 ) {});
loader.load('texture4.jpg',function ( texture4 ) {});
loader.load('texture5.jpg',function ( texture5 ) {});
```

What am I doing wrong?

[TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader)

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Your title is not specific enough + if you can try to provide a link to some code + I don't know three.js but I would suggest that you are missing something related with executing your code only after all textures have been loaded (callback problems).

Comment: just re-read the question ... what is the actual nature of the problem

Comment: Just take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010165/three-js-textureloader

Comment: Your not doing anything with the texture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The loader returns the texture, its actually pretty straightforward:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture1 = loader.load('texture1.jpg');
var texture2 = loader.load('texture2.jpg');
```

You can see that the r74dev examples already got updated with the new syntax: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_decals.html#L49-L51

Comment: According to the documentation this does not true any more: [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader)
There is a callback that you need to use, called onLoad.

Comment: You *can* use that callback, but you dont *have* to. See this working example where I am loading two textures and using them in the scene: http://jsfiddle.net/f17Lz5ux/5398/

Comment: or have a look to the code - there is an empty texture object returned, but the "onLoad" function tells you, when the object is "ready" https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e4629dd3df9b72115b332406a36c56f6f6d1286e/src/loaders/TextureLoader.js#L16

Answer (score 2):

You could use promise to load all textures async like this way:

```
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = Promise.all([loader.load('texture1.jpg'), loader.load('texture2.jpg')], (resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(texture);
}).then(result => {
    // result in array of textures
});
```

Comment: that does not make sense to me - load returns a texture object, therefore awaiting them in promise.all would almost instantly resolve, even though the textures are not loaded, so you would need to wrap the load function like e.g. new Promise((resolve,reject)=>loader.load(texture,resolve,()=>{},reject));

Comment: @mick yes right, this was just a short version. You can likely you explained set to the loader extra a Promise extension with: new Promise((resolve, reject) => { loader.load(textureSource, texture  resolve(texture)) }); So it would be wrapped in two Promises to go for sure.