# Draw Texture to Custom Shape in Three.js

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl

I have drawn an irregular quadrilateral. Now I want to map as image to the quadrilateral as texture. I can assign particular color to the quadrilateral but not image. What is the error I am having?

```
var camera = new THREE.Camera(
    35,                       // Field of view
    window.innerWidth / 600,  // Aspect ratio
    .1,                       // Near plane distance
    10000                     // Far plane distance
);
camera.position.set(3,1,100);
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

var material_4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    wireframe: true
});

var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 00);
var v4 = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 00);

geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(v1));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(v2));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(v3));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(v4));

geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(0,2,3,1));

geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
    new THREE.UV(0, 0),
    new THREE.UV(0, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 0)
]);

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00cc00   });
var bookCover = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
bookCover.map = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('4.png');

//var object = new THREE.Mesh(geom,material_4); // THis works
//var object = new THREE.Mesh(geom,material);  //This works
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geom,bookCover); // this doesnot work why?

object.overdraw=true;
scene.addChild(object);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of three.js are you using? In newer versions `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` is deprecated (Check [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35015251/1697459)). In latest versions you should use [`THREE.TextureLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader) instead.

`THREE.TextureLoader` works asynchronous so you have to use [the `onLoad` callback](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader.load) (second param of the `load` method) for applying the texture to your material:

```
var onLoad = function(texture){
    bookCover.map = texture;
    bookCover.needsUpdate = true;
}
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('4.png', onLoad);
```