# THREE.js Geometry map does not appear

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

[image]

Following I'm loading a image map on a custom geometry,
it represents the brown colored geometry on the picture above:

```
var aqua_ground_geo = new THREE.Geometry();

var top0 = new THREE.Vector3(aqua_ground_geo_x_NEG, user_data['aqua_soil_calc_b_y'], aqua_ground_geo_z_NEG);
var top1 = new THREE.Vector3(aqua_ground_geo_x_POS, user_data['aqua_soil_calc_b_y'], aqua_ground_geo_z_NEG);
var top2 = new THREE.Vector3(aqua_ground_geo_x_NEG, user_data['aqua_soil_calc_f_y'], aqua_ground_geo_z_POS);

aqua_ground_geo.vertices.push(top0);
aqua_ground_geo.vertices.push(top1);
aqua_ground_geo.vertices.push(top2);

aqua_ground_geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2) );

aqua_ground_geo.computeFaceNormals();
aqua_ground_geo.computeVertexNormals();

var textureUrl = "http://www.lifeguider.de/wp-content/uploads/aquag/bodengrund/dennerle_kies_naturweiss_1-2mm.jpg";
var aqua_bodengrund_tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( textureUrl );
var aqua_bodengrund_mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    map: aqua_bodengrund_tex,
    color: 0xffffff,
} );
aqua_bodengrund_mat.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
aqua_bodengrund_mat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

var aqua_bodengrund = new THREE.Mesh( aqua_ground_geo,aqua_bodengrund_mat);
```

On a simple `THREE.BoxGeometry` all works as expected with the same material (it represents the cube in the picture above):

```
var lala = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
var lala2 = new THREE.Mesh( lala,aqua_bodengrund_mat);
```

I'm not an expert in 3D, what is missing in my code that the image texture will be shown correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the texture in the callback of the `THREE.TextureLoader`. Check also the documentation **[here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader)**; the second argument (`onLoad`) is the callback.

```
var textureUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/textures/crate.gif";
var aqua_bodengrund_mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff
});
var onLoad = function( texture ){
    aqua_bodengrund_mat.map = texture;
    aqua_bodengrund_mat.needsUpdate = true;
}
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load( textureUrl, onLoad );
```

See **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/4yhp0ua5/)** for a demo.

---

### UPDATE

In case you have a custom geometry you also need to calculate the UVs for showing the texture correctly. I used [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20774922/1697459) to calculate them in another **[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/4yhp0ua5/3/)**

**Note.** The UVs in my fiddle are calculated for faces in the XY plane, if your faces are in another plane you will have to update accordingly...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've just set up a duplicate of the fiddle. I've just replaced `THREE.BoxGeometry();` with `THREE.Geometry();` and added my already used sample code and the texture map stops working again. **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qashi/vs284Lna/)**

Comment: Ok the idea with the need of UV coordinates was the last sentence in my initial question, which was removed for some typo tuning ... Finaly you got me the answer to success. So, many many thanks, Wilt!